# TypeCast from double to int then from int to string

Tags: java, apache

please help me to type cast from double to int then string.
My Code is

```
excelPojo.setRiskIdEnd(String.valueOf(cell.getNumericCellValue()));
```

Comment: What type does setRiskIdEnd take and what type does getNumericCellValue return?

Comment: explain question bit more

Comment: Do you want to know how to cast `double` to `int` and `int` to `String`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you asking for this?

```
excelPojo.setRiskIdEnd(((int)cell.getNumericCellValue() /*trunc decimals*/) + "");
```

Comment: not exactly it will return the int ,but my requirement was get return type in string .I solved it and really thanks for yours response.                                                                   excelPojo.setRiskIdEnd(String.valueOf((int)cell.getNumericCellValue()))

Comment: string.valueOf(obj) or ""+obj are equivalent, both get the obj.toString() - the latter creates a new instance. Anyway if this was useful you should at least upvote :)